# What is the namespace for the map functions in XSLT 3.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

XSLT 3.0 defines some functions for a [map](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-xslt-30-20131212/#func-map-keys). I notice the prefix for these functions is 'map'. So how should we declare the namespace for 'map'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

XSLT 3.0 is a working draft, and this kind of thing has a habit of changing between drafts. In Saxon 9.5 the namespace URI is "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map". An earlier draft (and earlier Saxon version) used "http://www.w3.org/2011/xpath-functions/map".

### 2019 UPDATE

XSLT 3.0 was finalized in 2017, using the namespace "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map", and this namespace has been supported in Saxon in all releases subsequent to 9.5